# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects while dumping nn4_small2_pretrained model from Keras-Openface Project

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pickle, openfaces

I was trying to implement Facial Recognition using the pretrained models from Keras-Openface Project and amazingly explained and implimented by Martin Krasser [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/krasserm/face-recognition/blob/master/face-recognition.ipynb?flush_cache=true)

> The OpenFace project provides pre-trained models that were trained with the public face recognition datasets FaceScrub and CASIA-WebFace. The Keras-OpenFace project converted the weights of the pre-trained nn4.small2.v1 model to CSV files which were then converted here to a binary format that can be loaded by Keras with load_weights

The Code is simply :

```
nn4_small2_pretrained = create_model()
nn4_small2_pretrained.load_weights('weights/nn4.small2.v1.h5')
```

Before going to the error to give more insight on what's happening in create_model(), you can go through the code [here](https://github.com/krasserm/face-recognition/blob/6e80ac75c805f49f7aa1acc7f21f2ed6c8f9b5cc/model.py#L15)

Now I need **nn4_small2_pretrained** in my *predict.py* file (It is initially a part of train.py to train my custom images), but if I do

```
from train import nn4_small2_pretrained
```

Or write the code

```
nn4_small2_pretrained = create_model()
nn4_small2_pretrained.load_weights('weights/nn4.small2.v1.h5')
```

all over again, then the prediction file takes a lot of time to compile as it goes through the whole process again. So to resolve this, I tried to dump the model in a pickle file like so

```
# Save the nn4 pretrained model to pickle file
f = open('pretrained_model.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(nn4_small2_pretrained, f)
```

When I run the code it gives me this error

```
    File "train.py", line 24, in <module>
        pickle.dump(nn4_small2_pretrained, f)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I have started with Deel Learning Models and Pickle recently and I cannot figure out what's wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the `create_model()` creates an instance of Keras Model. If it is a Keras Model then you can save the model using `model.save(filepath)`.
Refer this [link](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) for other options.

Comment: I tried this approach. But loading the model using load_model('xyx.h5')  gives the error 'tf not defined; even though I imported tensorflow in every associated file (just to be sure)

Comment: Are you sure that you used `tensorflow as tf`?

Comment: You have to pass tf as a custom object: `load_model('yourmodel', custom_objects={'tf': tf}`